# Suspicious new user accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, spam

Just found this while browsing the bottom of new users page.

[image]

All accounts start with **w88**, followed by a random word and a number. Most of them have set "Bangkok Thiland" as their location. Some of them even have "spam account" as their bio. You can also see these accounts by [searching for w88](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation) in the users tab.

Comment: Just curious: Why were you on the bottom of the new-users page? ;)

Comment: Just an accident :) was searching for my profile but clicked on the wrong page number in the wrong tab instead :P

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are spam accounts. Their about me says "spam account" because recently a couple of moderators have been editing the original content (which may get indexed by search engines and benefit the spammers' SEO) out and applying the change network-wide (we can only destroy the account on our site, so editing the profile is the only way to do something about it on other sites).

Don't bother paying much attention to them. There's still disagreement on the practice of moderators modifying their network profile but they are just profile spammers. You should ignore them; some moderators like myself destroy them, some hunt them down actively, and some just totally ignore them. They're not really for users to see (probably) anyway, just to abuse SE for search engine indexing.

Comment: Are these spam accounts present network-wide? [Because, I found them in Chem.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?page=45&tab=newusers) [cc @AlphaLife]

Comment: @NilayGhosh Yes, they tend to copy their profile over onto many sites, often upwards of 100+ to 150+ or even the entire network. The problem is on every site, some have it worse due to lower legitimate activity, others don't really need to do anything about them.